# jq select record from array with min or max value of field

Tags: json, max, jq, min

I have a json with records like this:

```
[
 {"number":1},
 {"number":3}
]
```

and want to select (filter) a record with a max or min value of the field "number".

I can get a min or max value of "number" like this:

`$ echo '[{"number":1},{"number":3}]' | jq ' [ .[].number ] | min'`

(emits 1)

and I can output booleans:

```
$ echo '[{"number":1},{"number":3}]' | jq '.[].number==([ .[].number ] | min)'
true
false
```

but when I try to put that together with select, it fails:

```
$ echo '[{"number":1},{"number":3}]' | jq 'map(select(.[].number==([ .[].number ] | min)))'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index number with string "number"
```

I feel like I am close, but stuck. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please improve the wording to make it clearer whether you want a minimal element and/or all the minimal elements. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
([ .[].number ] | min) as $m| map(select(.number== $m))
```

See https://jqplay.org/s/bUwtNrfAE-

### first

To retrieve the first minimal item:

```
([ .[].number ] | min) as $m| first(.[]|select(.number== $m))
```

### min_by, minimal_by, etc

jq has the built-ins `max_by` and `min_by`, as documented at
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions

For a definition of `maximal_by`, see the jq cookbook at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#find-the-maximal-elements-of-an-array-or-stream. That section also has stream-oriented definitions.

Comment: Thanks! It turned out that max_by and min_by did the thing for me: `echo '[{"number":1},{"number":3}]' | jq 'min_by(.number)'`, but thanks again for showing the trick with a variable!